# Can one always find a Schwarz antiderivative locally?

Tags: complex-analysis

The Schwarz derivative of a holomorphic function is defined as $$ Sf = \frac{f'''}{f'}  - \frac{3}{2} \left(    \frac{f''}{f'} \right)^2 ;$$ see the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative. Now, I wonder if given a holomorphic $\phi$, one can always locally find $f$ with $Sf = \phi$.

**Claim:** The answer is yes. The Wikipedia page states that given two linearly-independent holomorphic solutions to $$f'' + \phi f = 0, $$ for any chosen $\phi$, the ratio $f_1/f_2$ is a solution to $Sf = \phi.$ By a complex analogue of the Picard ODE theorem, such an equation can always be solved (modulo warbling about poles) and then we have found a Schwarz antiderivative of $\phi$.

The only problem I can see is, what if there are not two linearly independent solutions to $f'' + \phi f = 0$? Can this happen, and what can be said about antiderivatives in that case? My knowledge of ODEs is very limited, as you can tell...

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need **one** solution of 
$$f'' + \frac{\phi}{2} f = 0$$ 
so that $$(-2\frac{f'}{f})' = -2\frac{f''}{f}+2\frac{f'^2}{f^2}=\phi+\frac{1}{2}(-2\frac{f'}{f})^2$$

and with $ g' = \frac{C}{f^2},\frac{g''}{g'} = -2\frac{f'}{f}$ you get

$$S(g) = \phi$$

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't this mean $ \phi = \left( \frac{g''}{g'}  \right)' +  \left( \frac{g''}{g'}  \right)^2, $ whereas $  Sg = \left( \frac{g''}{g'}  \right)' - \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{g''}{g'}  \right)^2  $...?

Comment: @LatimerLeviosa I changed a few things

Comment: I think it's still not right - in the second displayed formula, the 2's just shoudn't be there =/

Comment: @LatimerLeviosa add a constant $2$ somewhere

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch.